# Getting the user ID of the user who created a taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I need to get the user information of the user who created a taxonomy term. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

try to do this:

1. Add a field called 'Author' like a [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference)
2. alter the form to prepopulate this field

   ```
   function customodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
   print_r($form_id);  
   if( $form_id == 'taxonomy-form-term' && isset($form['field_author']) ){ 

     print_r($form['field_author']['nid']['nid']['#value']);  
     global $user;    
     $form['field_author']['nid']['nid']['#value'] == $user->uid;

     }  
   }
   ```

I put some print_r so you can debug this code fast.

Answer (score 0):

Only nodes have author information attached, not taxonomy terms.

If you need to access author information you may be better off making a content type to store your data as opposed to a taxonomy vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomy terms are actually entities, to which you can add fields from "Manage fields."

Add a user entity reference field, and make it mandatory. Whenever you add a new term, associate the user ID to to the taxonomy term using the field you just created.

You can also hide the field using `hook_form_alter()`, and populate the field using the entity pre-save technique.